# Is possible to make RowReduce more efficient?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, parallelization

I have huge matrices (not square ones, the rows are many more than columns), like 85k rows and 50k columns. I would like to use RowReduce on these, but it takes too much time to do that. I need to find all the variables of these linear systems which go to 0. Is there an efficient way to do that, maybe also using parallel computation, given that I have 32 cores available?

Comment: Not much useful information here. What kind of matrices are these? Numeric or symbolic? Dense or sparse? Do the matrices possess any other special structure. For what exactly to you need the row reduction? Maybe `QRDecomposition` or `SingularDecomposition` serves a better purpose.

Comment: In general, Gaussian elimination is _not_ parallelizable. But for numerical purposes, one may _cheat_ without introducing too much error. For example, `PARDISO` is a linear solver that can  compute _approximate_ LU-factorizations of sparse square matrices in parallel that still serve very well as preconditioners for iterative linear solvers.

Comment: `RowReduce` is already parallelized for me on real, complex, and integer matrices (Mac, Intel i7).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The matrices are sparse and numeric, as far as I can see there are only integers numbers. I need to find all the variables of these linear systems which go to 0. Running 'RowReduce' takes too much time, it is inefficient and sometimes it also fails to end the command. I need a more efficient way, and I was thinking at doing something on parallel cores, given that i have 32 cores available. But I am open to new suggestions to solve the problem in an efficient way.

Comment: If the matrices are not ill conditioned, it could be much faster if you convert the integers to machine reals.